# How to AutoFill a column without knowing the row or column reference?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet I would like to AutoFill text I added to the last column in a spreadsheet.

I've managed to figure out the code to type in the last column. I keep getting errors when I try to autofill down.

The code is finding the last row and column without any issue.

**my code**

```
Sub Rename_Name_and_Two()

    Dim colLast As Long

    'For first row. To change rows, alter the Cells number
    colLast = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' Finds the last row
     Dim lastRow As Long
     lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    'Now for some data:
     Cells(1, colLast + 1) = "Secondary First Name"
     ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Selection, lastRow)

End Sub
```

Feel free to point me in the right direction.

Comment: So you're just wanting to autofill "Secondary First Name" down to the last row? It would also help if you provided details on your error.

Comment: What are the addresses of ActiveCell and Selection when you run `ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Selection, lastRow)`?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Yes. I want to autofill Secondary First Name down to the last row.

This is the error I'm receiving:

Run-time error '1004':

Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald I assumed it would select the active cell from the last line of code. From your statement, it sounds like I had an inaccurate assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't actually need `AutoFill`, since you are copying a *constant* string

so you may want to use:

```
Sub Rename_Name_and_Two()
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange ' reference currently active sheet 'UsedRange', i.e. the "rectangular" range embracing all used cells 
        .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(, 1).Value = "Secondary First Name" ' resize referenced range (i.e. 'UsedRange') to one column only and offset it by its columns number (-> you get a one column range at the right of 'UsedRange') and assign its cells the value "Secondary First Name"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: should I add your code to my code or replace my code altogether? Also, how does your code know to add the information to the last cell?

Comment: replace it altoghether. my code uses `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` which references the _rectangular_ range embracing all used cells in the _active_ sheet. Hence, `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count` is the number of its columns, and offsetting it by that number you get in the first column out of the `UsedRange`

Comment: your code worked. Could you explain what the code is doing? I would like to understand why it works.

Comment: This makes sense.

What about Resize(,1)? What is being resized?

Comment: see comments in edited code. once you reference an `object` (like a `Range` is) in a `With ... End With` block, then all its `members` are a "dot" away inside that block

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `ActiveCell`, `Selection` etc.

In your line `Cells(1, colLast + 1) = "Secondary First Name"`, you are writing down the text in the first empty column, but you are never `Selecting` it, this is why at the next line `ActiveCell.AutoFill...` it's not necessarily dragging this cell.

The Range that you want to `AutoFill` should be, from the first cell, which is `Cells(1, colLast + 1)`, until the last row which is `Cells(lastRow, colLast + 1)`.

**Note**: your `lastRow` is looking for the last row in column A, if there are columns with more rows, you will still `FillDown` up to last row in column A.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Rename_Name_and_Two()

Dim colLast As Long, lastRow As Long

' use With statement to fully qualify your cells and range with the worksheet
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' modify "sheet1" to your sheet's name

    ' For first row. To change rows, alter the Cells number
    colLast = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' Finds the last row (in column A)
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Now for some data:
    .Cells(1, colLast + 1).Value2 = "Secondary First Name"

    ' drag the text untill last row (in column A)
    .Cells(1, colLast + 1).AutoFill Destination:=.Range(.Cells(1, colLast + 1), .Cells(lastRow, colLast + 1))
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you also set `xRange` ('Range(.Cells(1, colLast + 1), .Cells(lastRow, colLast + 1))`
) and then `xRange.FillDown`? Where `xRange` is the variable name of your choice.

Comment: I tried to use this code.

Was I suppose to copy the entire code? Option Explicit did not fall underneath the grey that signifies a new sub routine.

I also get the following Compile error when I run the program:

Ambiguous name detected: Rename_Name_and_Two

After changing the name, I get the next Run-time error '9' message:

Subscript out of range

It highlights the with following code:

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vortex") ' modify "sheet1" to your sheet's name